How to patch a Cargo git dependency that contains a workspace
I'm trying to automatically vendor sources for Cargo packages/crates for offline installation.
For "crates-io" this is easily done with a replace-with = "vendored-sources" in the .cargo/config.toml
For git dependencies like

pubgrub = { git = "https://github.com/astral-sh/pubgrub", rev = "3f0ba760951ab0deeac874b98bb18fc90103fcf7" }

I can also:

Download the repo as a .tar.gz
Unpack to /vendor
Generate a .cargo-checksum.json with (only) a "package" checksum
Put the following in `.cargo/config.toml:
[patch."https://github.com/astral-sh/pubgrub"]
pubgrub = { path = "/vendor/pubgrub" }



However there are also workspace packages like https://github.com/astral-sh/reqwest-middleware which contain multiple crates like reqwest-middleware and reqwest-retry whch using the same approach yield:

found a virtual manifest at /vendor/reqwest-middleware/Cargo.toml instead of a package manifest

If I point the path to the subfolder, i.e. /vendor/reqwest-middleware/reqwest-middleware it fails with

Unable to update https://github.com/astral-sh/reqwest-middleware?rev=21ceec9a5fd2e8d6f71c3ea2999078fecbd13cbe#21ceec9a
Caused by:
can't checkout from 'https://github.com/astral-sh/reqwest-middleware': you are in the offline mode (--offline)

What is the preferred approach to handle this?
With some trial and error I found:
[source.reqwest-middleware]
directory = "/vendor/reqwest-middleware"

[source.doesntmatter]
git = "https://github.com/astral-sh/reqwest-middleware"
rev = "21ceec9a5fd2e8d6f71c3ea2999078fecbd13cbe"
replace-with = "reqwest-middleware"

But that seems overly verbose and I need to make sure to not place them in the same folder as the crates.io vendored sources or it will fail with the same virtual-package error and "failed to update replaced source registry crates-io"
